# Error while passing string from time&date from an activity's fab to another fragment's textview

Tags: java, android

I have a problem here with passing string from time&date from an activity's floatingactionbar to a textview.

Here is the fab:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Add a new queue", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();

            Fragment fragment2=new Notifications();
            Bundle arg= new Bundle();
            String time= DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            arg.putString("date",time);
            fragment2.setArguments(arg);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment2);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();


            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_notifications);
        }
```

The error "unsolved method" from Android studio occurs here:

```
                String time= DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Here is the code for the fragment to receive the string value:

```
public class Notifications extends Fragment {
TextView servingqueue;
TextView date;
String dateGET;

DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mServingQueue = mRootRef.child("ServingQueue");


public Notifications() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle pb=getArguments();
    dateGET=pb.getString("date");


    mServingQueue.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Double number = dataSnapshot.getValue(Double.class);
            servingqueue.setText(String.valueOf(number));

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragmentid.queueServing);
    servingqueue = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.queueServing);
    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
    date.setText(dateGET);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using date or time picker from android studio too?
 Try this:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Comment: I'm using textview. How does that connect to my code?